# Planar faces issue

Tags: modeling

[image]I am designing a climbing wall. I use sketchup mostly and today is the first day I downloaded blender, pretty excited. Here's my questions:

I can't seem to make the faces in my climbing wall mesh of faces from sketchup to be planar. I want to take my messy sketchup mesh of a climbing wall which has too much triangulation of tris that are all on different planes, I want to take the mesh of different angles tris and calculate all of the surfaces that should be single planar quads and not two triangles to be planar quads. Meaning making the faces planar would take the whole mesh and try not to distort it much. I'm not looking to make the whole object planar as one flat plane, just want to simplify the mesh and remove a lot of the triangles. Can you please guide me to the best way of doing this? I know a fair bit about modelling and from my understanding I might not be able to do what I'm asking but I hope it's possible. I just want to simplify my mesh and make more faces planar.

The one face has many triangles, but I want to make a lot of the triangles in general dissapear.

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots of that topology you need to change? Because there is a simple command, go to edit mode, select all faces, press F3 and search for Tris to Quads... This will transform all tris to quads but it won't work if your topology is so much triangulated that Blender won't be able to calculate how to make it into quads... that's why we need to see what your problem is

Comment: What MikoCG suggests, won't make the internal triangulation of newly formed quads coplanar. That is, Blender doesn't enforce all vertices of a single face to sit on the same plane. In order to makes two triangles co-planar, you need to rotate one of them - which is likely to also rotate and stretch connected triangles, including those you already aligned, by making them not coplanar to their *"sibling"* again. 

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me you guys! I need all the help I can get. Yea here are some screenshots. So what I want to do is just make selected faces planar without effecting nearby faces too much and I can go around and make everything planar how I'd like to. Any suggestions for that? The real problem is that I wonder if I make two selected faces planar, if other faces will now be out of alignment, being a constant battle..... I'm not looking to draw this entirely manually, maybe some of it redrawn in blender, because I'm doing all of my drawing in sketchup first and usig blender to clean it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can certainly select two adjacent triangles and join them into a quad, but if the faces  are at a large angle to each other it won't work. Also if the surrounding vertical aren't close to planar, it'll have to affect them. I feel like there's something missing.  With regards to the one face with lots of internal triangles, you're better off deleting that face, merging the extra verts to the corners, and then use Fill hole to recreate the face.

Comment: Ok thanks Dale! Is it possible to create planar meshes from scratch in blender? So I would just recreate this climbing wall in blender as as quad mesh? And when I move the quad mesh in different directions, I would retain quads and not get triangles, or many triangles. If this is possible, creating a planar type mesh I can manipulate in blender, could you link me to a good tutorial!! Thanks so much for your help so far.